# SQLAlchemy cast to PostgreSQL TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, sqlalchemy, timestamp

I have seen that in postgresql we can cast datetime to `timestamp` or `timestamptz` which is `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` or `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

For instance using `psql(Postgres shell)`:

```
db=# select '2023-03-31 00:00:00'::timestamp;

      timestamp      
---------------------
 2023-03-31 00:00:00
```

or

```
db=# select '2023-03-31 00:00:00'::timestamptz;

      timestamptz       
------------------------
 2023-03-31 00:00:00+00
```

The second example is exactly what I'm trying to do with SqlAlchemy.

I know that we can use `Model.created_date.cast(TIMESTAMP)` which is like the first example, but I need to cast `created_date` to `timestamptz`.

The purpose of doing this is to extract some parts of that date in many different time zones.

in addition, the field in my model is like this:

```
created_date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

Comment: Per the docs [Timestamp](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.TIMESTAMP): *Use the TIMESTAMP.timezone argument in order to enable “TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE” for these backends.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `timezone=True` to the `TIMESTAMP` type for PostgreSQL:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, cast, select, text
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import TIMESTAMP

engine = create_engine("postgresql://…")

qry = select(cast(text("'2023-03-31 00:00:00'"), TIMESTAMP(timezone=True)))
print(qry.compile(engine))
# SELECT CAST('2023-03-31 00:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE) AS anon_1
```